# What causes Button to add extra height to containers?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I'm working on a non-standard button that is deliberately small. I want the row to only be as tall as the text in the children. I'd like text to precede the button horizontally and for the button to have a text-only appearance. `TextButton`, however, appears to add extra padding to the parent `Row`'s parent. I've tried many combinations of `height(IntrinsicSize)`, `defaultMinSize`, `heightIn`, `wrapContentSize`, and other modifiers. Notice the button background extending beyond the `Row`'s height (the selected element in the preview) in screenshot demonstrating the problem:

[image: preview demonstrating the issue]

The *only* solution appears to be setting an explicit `height(Dp)`. The problem with this solution to me is that it will not react appropriately to system-level text scaling.

[image: preview of the scenario with explicit Dp height]

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Text("Here is a linky button:")

        TextButton(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier
                .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp)
                .background(Color.Cyan),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        ) {
            Text("Linky Button")
        }
    }
}
```

So in total, I have two questions:

1. Where is the extra height coming from?
2. Is there a more flexible solution than setting an explicit `.height(Dp)`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TextButton` which is a Material component.
Material design has specifications to have minimum dimensions for clickable components. So, there is padding added for that.

If you need a clickable text, you can use `ClickableText` or any composable with `Modifier.clickable` to fit your use-case.

Comment: I'm aware of the material design spec and the fact this is a material component—which is why I suggested it's non-standard, but typically a UI component library will allow overriding every aspect of components it provides. It would be disappointing if the UI library enforced that requirement with no recourse for deliberate divergence.

I debated whether `ClickableText` would play well with screen readers or come with other gotchas since this element's purpose is ultimately most similar to a button, but that might be the way to go. I'll explore.

Comment: Material Design is Google's design system. They create the design guidelines. We can always use foundation components if it does not suit our requirements.